# Bootstrap 3 two responsive rows next to each other?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and trying to solve this what's mocked on the image. I used one row with two cols, and they are next to each other like in the image, but when I resize to mobile I want the right side to fall beneath the left. Any help is appreciated, thank you.
[image]

Code sample:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-xs-4 col-offset-xs-1">
     <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="col-xs-4">
    <div className="row">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.black{background-color:#000; height:320px;}
.red{background-color:#F00; height:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 black">
          black
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 red">
          one
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 red">
          two
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 red">
          three
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't move the *right half of the container* underneath for *xs screens*.

Comment: Basically just copied and pasted my answer and added some CSS, nice work!

Comment: i was writing this piece of html when no answers are on there, don't be gelous. Oh and... you're using sm, so in xs sizes it will break, mooving down the right half under the first one. Cheers!

Comment: It's not jealousy, it's providing wrong and copied answers, that's all.

Comment: not wrong, not copied, it's a basic structure with bootstrap as you can see. I can write it fast if they finaly add intellisense on snippet generator, huh?
Next time i'll write on my IDE and paste the code to avoid your teeny comments ;)

Comment: Hey guys. Any chance to make a small margin between left and right? Because adding margin to the custom class in css breaks the responsivnes. Thanks.

Comment: @NewbieOnRails check my answer, you have the margins there.

Comment: You can retrieve the background padding-like. Search background attachment and background color documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap allows nesting your elements easily, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/denea/DTcHh/25594/

```
      <div className="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="first">
               <h1>1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="second">
              <div class="row">
                <h1>2</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <h1>3</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <h1>4</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

and read this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap allows for nesting which will provide what you need:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    Left column
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Right column, row 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Right column, row 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Right column, row 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[More info here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using flexbox and media query

```
 @media (max-width: 360px) {
    .container > .row {
          display:flex;
          flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
    }
 }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xs3joev8/1/